# Facebook FB.ui, Feed message obj not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

Well, I have this problem regarding about FB.ui about message attribute,property/object or whatever is it called. (doesn't know what it's called though, my bad.)

I saw this code at some site:

http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FB.ui#method%3a_.27permissions.request.27

And here's the specific part that I'm concerned with.

[image]

It's **not** working for **me at least...**

Well this is my code,

```
function postToFeed() { //Facebook Share Function
  // calling the API ...
  var obj = {
    method: 'feed',
    display: "iframe",
    message: "Hey Hey Lol",
    link: "http://www.facebook.com/pages/<?php echo $fbp_name; ?>/<?php echo $fbp_id; ?>?sk=app_xxxxx",
    picture: "http://www.compibot.com/<?php echo $image_folder;  ?>/<?php echo $event_info[4]; ?>",
    name: "<?php echo $event_info[1]; ?>",
    caption: '<?php echo "Expires in: " . $mdy_expiry; ?>',
    description: "<?php echo $event_info[2]; ?>",
    actions: [{ name: 'Vote', link: 'https://www.facebook.com/<?php echo $fbp_id ?>'}]
  };

  function callback(response) {
    addScore("<?php echo $event_table; ?>", "fbshare_point");
    $("#fb_share").addClass("success");
  }
  FB.ui(obj, callback);
}
```

And this is the output that I'm getting that will be shown below.

[image]

Instead of saying **Hey Hey Lol** in textarea of facebook share. it was just blank.

I even changed the method to **"stream.publish"** still not working.

Any idea how to fix this stuff?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pre-filling the `message` parameter does not work any more – Facebook removed that a long time ago.

You are *not* supposed to pre-fill any text when sharing on Facebook – the message should be *typed in* by the user themselves.

---

If you really want to do this, you have to make a post via API in the background – which of course requires the user to connect to your app and give adequate permission. And even then you are not supposed to post a message that the user did not type in themselves into a form somewhere – and Facebook easily figures out if your app posts the same (or largely similar) messages for different users, and that will limit visibility of your posts drastically, and could even lead to your app getting blocked.